# MOSS 2007 on Windows Server 2008 behind ISA 2006 with smart card authorization

Tags: 2007, kerberos

I am currently trying to upgrade my two WFEs from 32 bit Windows Server 2003 to 64 bit Windows Server 2008. I also have a 64 bit Windows server 2008 in the farm as an index server, and a 64 bit SQL 2005 box running Windows server 2008. I am using kerberos authentication to allow for smart card auth on the ISA 2006 server.

After upgrading one of the front ends I am unable to access it through ISA. I get the multiple prompts even though I am entering valid credentials. When looking in the sever logs there are numerous kerberos errors referencing a null sid.

Does anyone else have this configuration working? and if so please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably having problems with the new "feature" in IIS 7 - Kernel Mode Authentication

> Kernel Mode Authentication uses the
>   SPNs on the computer account, even if
>   the application pool runs on a
>   different service account. This is a
>   problem when you are running a
>   Sharepoint farm with more than one
>   frontend webserver

http://nico.berlee.nl/sharepoint-using-kerberos-on-windows-2008/